# SwiftUI Mac Catalyst Scrolling not working with StackNavigationViewStyle

Tags: macos, scroll, swiftui, stack-navigator

I have the following problem and I hope someone can help me out...

As soon as I use .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) the Mac Catalyst App does only scroll for a little while in the "Detailview"

Here my examplecode:

Listview:

```
struct Liste: View {
    var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("Hello World")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("Hello World")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("Hello World")
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

Detailview:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Form{
                Section{
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

In the following video, you can see what happens:

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: StackNavigationViewStyle is unavailable for native macOS do you mean Mac Catalyst?

Comment: Sorry, yes I mean Mac Catalyst

Comment: Your `DetailView` doesn't have a `ScrollView` I think the issue is that is scrolls at all

Comment: But it has the Form-Stack and on iOS there is no problem at all... Also: As soon as I remove the ".navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())" it works fine.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution? Thank you

Comment: No unfortunately not. I used ScrollView instead.